# Releasing Connections back to MongoDB Connection Pool

Tags: c#, mongodb, insert, threadpool, connection-pooling

I have a C# application that performs multi-threaded inserts via the C# ThreadPool into MongoDB. However, I have been getting a `TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for a MongoConnection`. I'm using the MongoServer.RequestStart method, which should be releasing the connection back into the MongoClient connection pool.

Also, the threadpool has a minimum of 4 threads and maximum of 8, while the Mongo connection pool has a default of 100 connections, so I shouldn't be running out of connections.

So why am I getting this error?

Here's the method which is passed into the threadpool. `_client` is a MongoClient instance variable.

```
public void BatchInsert(string collectionName, BinaryPacketDocument[] documents, int batchSize) {
        MongoServer server = _client.GetServer();
        MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase(_databaseName);
        using (server.RequestStart(database)) {
            MongoCollection collection = database.GetCollection(collectionName);
            collection.InsertBatch(documents);
            StatisticsManager.GetCounter("logs").Add(batchSize);    
        }
    }
```

And here's how I pass it into the threadpool.

```
private void SendWorkToThreadPool(string collectionName, BinaryPacketDocument[] documents, int batchSize) {
        if (documents.Length != 0) {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => _inserter.BatchInsert(collectionName, documents, batchSize)); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that my thread pool was not actually being limited to 8 threads. If you pass in 0 as one of the arguments to ThreadPool.SetMax/Min threads, it will fail to set the max (but not explicitly).